# how to avoid recording redundant data with MVC

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a class with two properties (name,family).
I have written code for insert into database without problems, but I don't know how to write the code to check if the data already exists?

I need sample for MVC 4 or higher.

Thanks in advance.

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="Name,Description")] ColorApplication colorapplication) 
{ 
    if (ModelState.IsValid) 
    { 
        db.ColorApplications.Add(colorapplication);      
        db.SaveChanges(); 
        return RedirectToAction("Index"); 
    } 
    return View(colorapplication); 
}
```

Comment: Can we see your code? Hard to help without seeing what you've tried

Comment: Post a little code so we can help you. How are you accessing the database? Are you using Entity Framework, SQLCommand class, some other ORM?

Comment: public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="Name,Description")] ColorApplication colorapplication)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.ColorApplications.Add(colorapplication);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(colorapplication);
        }

Comment: Use a linq statement to query the database meeting your conditions. If the query returns a result then don't do the update

Comment: If your entity is properly indexed, (ie. has a unique primary key for each instance) then you can use EF extension method `AddOrUpdate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanna use the DbSet, there are the `Remove()` or `RemoveRange()` options.

You can eighter remove one:

```
using (PersonContext db = new PersonContext())
{
    Person person = db.Persons.Where(t => t.Name == "My Name").FirstOrDefault<Person>();
    db.Persons.Remove(person);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Or give a list of entities that you want to remove:

```
using (PersonContext db = new PersonContext())
{
    List<Person> persons = db.Persons.Where(t => t.Name == "My Name").ToList();
    db.Persons.RemoveRange(persons);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

You can also use raw SQL statements if you need something more specific:

```
DELETE FROM PERSON WHERE NAME = 'My Name'
```